# FCM Topics Rate-Limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If you head over to Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging) for Topics, it mentions there's a rate-limit for new subscriptions.

> The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you
>   send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM
>   servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded")
>   response. Retry with exponential backoff.

Does anyone know or tested how many requests per minute/second you can make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling):

> The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per
>   project.

Click through to the documentation to read in more detail.

Comment: Never saw that, thanks Doug! But after a quick read, I’m under the impression that doing 1 request per client (iOS application) can easily get past the limit. Am I right?

Comment: So you're saying that you want to send 1 message to N devices using N topics, one topic for each device?  That doesn't seem like a good use of topic messaging.  It's better to send direct to the device token in that case.

Comment: No, let me try to explain.
Imagine a scenario with 2 channels, being "news" and "promotions". Some push notifications will only be sent to users that subscribed to "news" and others to "promotions".
So, at some point during the application flow, the user will be able to subscribe or unsubscribe to these channels. The documentation points out there's a rate-limit of 3000 QPS for subscribing/unsubscribing.
Is it common to get past this limit? Trying to figure out if this is an appropriate solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a different question now.  Subscribe rate is not related to fanout throttling.

Comment: My questions were always related to Subscription Rate, considering stackoverflow.com/questions/56933490.
Anyway based on the page you sent,  "The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per project."

Comment: They're not really related.  Subscriptions happen as directed by the client app, and the fanout happens as a result of messages sent from the server side in order to prevent someone from pumping too many topic messages through the system.  They operate independently of each other.  The client limit could be hit with no messages flowing through the system, and topic messages can be throttled with no client subscription activity involved.

Comment: But if all you needed to know was the subscription rate limit, yes, it's 3K.

Comment: I know they are not related. My question was always about the subscription rate.

Comment: What is QPS by the way?

Comment: QPS means Queries per second.